# Angular2 setting property in a table column programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am using primeng2 and I would like to set the frozen columns

I am retrieving columns from a rest API in JSON form

```
colheaders:any[] = [];

getColumnheaders(){
   this.bookService.getColumns()
     .subscribe(
      res=>{
       this.colheaders = res
       }
     )
 }
```

On the html I have

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" scrollable="true" frozenWidth="1200px" unfrozenWidth="600px" [style]="{'margin-top':'30px'}">

     <p-column sortable="true" *ngFor="let col of colheaders" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"
               [frozen]="col.frozen"></p-column>


 </p-dataTable>
```

The above p-column fails when setting its value to false

In a quick googling I found that I need not to set the value of frozen whether true or false

so for the frozen columns I should have something like

```
   <p-column sortable="true"  [frozen]="true"></p-column>
```

And the unfrozen columns should have

```
       <p-column sortable="true"></p-column>  //no frozen property
```

So how do I go about it

so in normal words should be something like this

```
 <p-column sortable="true" *ngFor="let col of colheaders"
               * *ngIf="(col.frozen)" //stuck on how to go on ></p-column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `<p-column>` tag to ng-`container`, which doesn't have any DOM representation, and then move `ngFor` in it. You can keep `ngIf` in `p-column`:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" scrollable="true" frozenWidth="1200px" unfrozenWidth="600px" [style]="{'margin-top':'30px'}">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let col of colheaders"> 
       <p-column sortable="true" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"
               *ngIf="col.frozen" [frozen]="true"></p-column>
       <p-column sortable="true" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"
               *ngIf="!col.frozen"></p-column>
    </ng-container>

</p-dataTable>
```